# How to set loading to false or true for each item in the rxjs angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

this is in my component for select item

```
this.test = this.string$.pip(
switchMap(() => {
  return this.list.checkBox(data)
})

this.test.subscribe((res) => {

}, (err) => {
  item.status = false
}

this.string.next(date);
```

i want to add loading for each item , for example i have list of data that i want when we have post request set loading just for that item , i test it with writing in the switchmap but it set for all items , or in the tap after and before switchmap like this following code but not worked

```
this.test = this.string$.pip(
tap(() => this.loading =true),
switchMap(() => {
  return this.list.checkBox(data)
}),
tap(() => this.loading = false
)
```

Comment: Take a look at a helper library I wrote ez-state, it does a lot of this for you, here is a demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzemhttps://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem I have not yet documented it but it is production ready and easy to use. This article on the library it replaces gives you most of the concepts https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create an item component in which you can hold the state for each item.

Example:

```
// Parent html
<app-item *ngFor="let item of ['A', 'B', 'C']" [item]="item"></app-item>
```

```
// child component
export class ItemComponent {

  @Input()
  item: string;

  pending$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private myAsyncService: MyAsyncService) {}

  onClick() {
    this.pending$.next(true);

    this.myAsyncService.getData().pipe(
      take(1),
    ).subscribe(
      () => this.pending$.next(false),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// child html
<button (click)="onClick()" [ngClass]="{ pending: pending$ | async }">{{ item }}</button>
```

```
// child css
.pending {
  background-color: red
}
```

```
// the service
getData(): Observable<number> {
    return timer(2000);
  }
```

In this example each button turns red for 2 seconds individually.

See Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14xsoe?file=src/app/my-async.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you would created a sample on stackblitz. This way it would be easier to identify problem and provide a solution. More importantly many things are unclear from the post.

1. Are you trying to load each individual data asynchronously?
2. Where are are trying to show the loader? Is it within the data item of list or is it a common loader?
3. Are you trying to show loader at the time of rendering or a loader while the data is being loaded from server.

Another point switchMap operator might not work here as it is purpose to cancel previous subscription and emit data from the latest. I hope this helps in articulating and presenting problem in a better way.

Comment: thank you for your response , as example i have an array of foods ,i want to select one food as post request and i want to show spinner just for this item not all ,i added loading and i want to set it to true when clicked and when response was success ,set it to false,the problem is in the slow 3G i have spinner for all items that are pending and i want to set true loading just for successful not canceled or pending

Comment: if you has an "array" of spinner (one spinner for each row), you need an array of variables loading

Comment: You can maintain a Hashmap of key/pair. Key can be your foodId and value can be your spinner status. I believe you are trying to show spinner for all the items in the list so you can map the key i.e. foodId in the ngFor and keep toggling the map items based on your selection.